# What does "consign" mean in this example?

Tags: meaning

I am reading the following definition of commit

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/commit

> 1c. to consign or record for preservation. Example: commit it to memory

Now I am trying to understand the word "consign" in the above entry.

Here are the choices for "consign":

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/consign

> 1: to give over to another's care
>
> 2: to give, transfer, or deliver into the hands or control of another; also : to commit especially to a final destination or fate (a writer *consigned* to oblivion)
>
> 3: to send or address to an agent to be cared for or sold

Why do none of these definitions fit perfectly?  In English am I supposed to invent my own figurative meaning to make it fit?

Comment: “to commit especially to a final destination”

Comment: [Consign](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/consign?q=consign). Explains it without the use of *commit*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the 2nd definition, particularly the bit after the colon.

> to commit especially to a final destination or fate (a writer
>   consigned to oblivion)

Of course, you're getting into circular definitions a bit there. Consign means to commit, which means to consign. Oddly enough every online dictionary I checked has this same issue.